# Fazer seleção a partir dos resultados obtidos da mesma

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Boa tarde,

Tenho as seguinte tabela..

```
*eventos*
----------------------------------------
| id_evento | id_projeto | nome_evento |
----------------------------------------
```

Estou precisando fazer uma procedure da seguinte forma:

***"Selecione os eventos em que o id_projeto sejam 1 com limite de 2 registros, mas se a quantidade de registros for menor que 2, selecione os últimos eventos registrados para completar a quantidade total de 2 registros."***

Detalhando... Eu preciso selecionar os registros que tenham determinado `id_projeto` mas se por acaso não houver registro(com esse id) eu preciso selecionar os últimos dois da tabela eventos, e se por acaso houver apenas 1, então preciso selecionar apenas mais 1 registro.

Espero ter sido claro. Qualquer dúvida eu respondo.

*obs.: Estou usando o banco mysql*

Comment: O resumo da questão é maior que a questão ue q q isso kkkk

Comment: @Francisco kkkkk verdade ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o `ORDER BY FIELD` junto ao `LIMIT` para fazer isso:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos ORDER BY FIELD(id_projeto, 1) DESC, id_evento DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: mas aí se tiver mais de dois eventos com o id_projeto 1, não serão exibidos

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Mas é exatamente isso que a pergunta está pedindo ue.

Comment: acho que na verdade tem q mostrar no mínimo dois registros, se tiver mais que bate com o id_projeto...tem q ser mostrado também

Comment: @Francisco exato.. Mas se por acaso, houver apenas um registro, ele vai puxar outro com outro id, certo?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis na verdade eu só preciso de 2 mesmo

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Sim. Pode testar.

Comment: @Francisco obrigado!

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Não sei seu conceito de limite, mas acho que você entendeu errado a questão.

Comment: "mas se por acaso, não houver registro com esse id, preciso selecionar os últimos 2" mas blz, entendi de outra forma...

Comment: cara...certeza que isso funciona? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df682a/1

Comment: @Rovann Linhalis ainda não testei...

Comment: a função Field vai retornar o índice do parametro dentro do campo, ou seja, vai trazer os que não possuem 1 sempre na frente, e depois os que possuem, aí outro problema, tendo id_projeto = 1 ou =10, a ordenação dos dois torna-se igual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Acho que você entendeu um pouco errado a função do FIELD, ele não vê se existe o valor na frente, ele tenta pegar exatamente aquele valor. Eu tinha esquecido do DESC, agora está funcionando perfeitamente: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df682a/12

Comment: Realmente, desculpe. @AndreiCoelho a sintaxe do Francisco vai ficar bem melhor para sua necessidade =]

Comment: Então, mas nesse caso http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df682a/24 ele deveria pegar o evento 9 também, mas está pegando o evento 2. Por isso ainda acho a resposta do @RovannLinhalis melhor por enquanto.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Só adicionar outro order by, editei minha resposta, da uma olhada.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Não tem com o que se desculpar, nem eu sei como essa função funciona direito, usei ela só 1 vez na vida kk

Comment: Legal! Obrigado a todos! Francisco e @RovannLinhalis

Answer (score 3):

Considerando a consulta pelo `id_projeto = 1` pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
select 
id_evento,id_projeto,nome_evento, 1 as prioridade
from eventos where id_projeto =1

union

select 
id_evento,id_projeto,nome_evento, 2 as prioridade
from eventos where id_projeto !=1

order by prioridade, id_evento desc
limit 2;
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df682a/4

Comment: Perfeito! Era exatamente isso!

Comment: =] estava tentando resolver da outra forma que havia entendido a questão

Comment: =) De qualquer forma, muito obrigado! Eu ia dar de cara na parede! rsrsrs